# Using Mapper.Map inside CreateMap

Tags: c#, automapper

If I have a list of objects inside an object like so:

```
//There is a class just like this InnerSource
public class InnerClass
{
   //Because why not
   public int[] Nums;
}
//There is a class OuterSource just like this but it has a List of
//InnerSource objects
public class OuterClass
{
   public IEnumerable<InnerClass> InnerObjects;
}
```

I thought this would be an elegant way to handle mapping an OuterSource object to an OuterClass object but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
public class CreateMaps
{
   public void CreateAllMaps()
   {
      Mapper.CreateMap<InnerSource, InnerClass>();
      Mapper.CreateMap<OuterSource, OuterClass>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.InnerObjects, opt => MapFrom(
         src => src.InnerSource));
   }
}
```

I've also tried using src => Mapper.Map, IEnumerable>(src.InnerSource) but that didn't work either. By didn't work I mean that instead of getting a list of InnerClass objects I got an empty list. I made sure that the InnerSource list has objects in it so I'm really at a loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually don't think you even need the `ForMember` line. Try just doing this:

```
public class CreateMaps
{
   public void CreateAllMaps()
   {
      Mapper.CreateMap<InnerSource, InnerClass>();
      Mapper.CreateMap<OuterSource, OuterClass>();
   }
}
```

Comment: For some reason when I use Mapper.Map<OuterSource, OuterClass>(outerSourceObject) I still end up with an empty array of InnerClass

Comment: You were totally right. I ended up calling .ToList().Add(InnerSource) on my list of inner source items. Thank you!